# Why do I get this error trying to start a Laravel application by "artisan serve" statment?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, php-5.5

I am pretty new in **PHP** and **Laravel** and I have the following prblem.

I have to work on a PHP application made using Laravel as framework.

I have retrieve this application and I have to start it by this **artisan** statment:

```
php artisan serve
```

The problem is that in the shell I am obatining this error message:

```
Andrea@Andrea-PC MINGW64 ~/Documents/Betrivius/betriviusExtranet
$ php artisan serve
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in C:\Users\Andrea\Documents\Betrivius\betr
iviusExtranet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php on line 476

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in C:\Users\Andrea\Documents\Betrivius\betrivius
Extranet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php on line 476
```

I am using **PHP 5.5.38** version.

```
Andrea@Andrea-PC MINGW64 ~/Documents/Betrivius/betriviusExtranet
$ php --version
PHP 5.5.38 (cli) (built: Jul 20 2016 11:16:06)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

What could be the problem? Maybe my PHP version doesn't not support something? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue and start my application?

Comment: This looks like there is a syntax error in the helpers.php on line 476. Can you post couple of lines from there so that it can be reviewed.

Comment: @VinitSarvade This is a Laravel class...it couldn't contains error...

Comment: Ok that case it's probably the PHP version. Laravel 5.3 needs atleast PHP 5.6.4.  Which Laravel version are u running.?

Comment: Any update on a resolution?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine this is still related to your version of PHP not supporting the `splat` operator. The line in question [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L478) is referencing a `splat` operator:

```
function event(...$args)
{
    return app('events')->fire(...$args);
}
```

which was [released in version `5.6`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat).